# Graphite - simple carbon installment

Tags: monitoring, graphite, statsd

I am trying to install the simplest carbon installation and have some queries.

For the documentation(http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html#the-carbon-daemons) this would just be carbon-cache.py. Is this correct?
I would only need the others for more complex situations:

carbon-relay.py serves two distinct purposes: replication and sharding.
carbon-aggregator.py can be run in front of carbon-cache.py to buffer metrics

Is my understanding correct?

If so can I remove there sections from the carbon.conf file?
Also I do not need the storage-aggregation.conf file?

One last question, What is port 7002 for and do I need it open for my simple installation.
I have read its for the "carbon-cache query port" but I dont understand this and cant find any more details on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this would just be carbon-cache.py. Is this correct?

Yes.

> carbon-relay.py serves two distinct purposes: replication and
>   sharding. carbon-aggregator.py can be run in front of carbon-cache.py
>   to buffer metrics

Yes. Though in practice, aggregation of metrics at the source (statsd, collectd, diamond) is better than *carrying them on till the very end* of the stack and then aggregating them. Though, the aggregator supports more complex multiple-metric aggregation rules.

> If so can I remove there sections from the carbon.conf file?

Yes you can.

> Also I do not need the storage-aggregation.conf file?

You don't.

> What is port 7002 for and do I need it open for my simple
>   installation. I have read its for the "carbon-cache query port" but I
>   dont understand this and cant find any more details on this.

Yes you need to leave it as is. The default query port for carbon-cache is 7002. This is where graphite-web queries carbon to ask for the metric information during rendering.

---

Edit-

i presumed you were looking at a bare minimal setup. For more complex metrics, it is advisable to have a storage-aggregation setup. It is a good idea to have `xFilesFactor` set to 0 so that even very little rates of metric input aren't ignored.

Then, it makes semantic sense if you sum counters and average timers while aggregation.

```
[counters_fall_here]
pattern = ^(Facebook\.counters)\.(production)
xFilesFactor = 0.0
aggregationMethod = sum

[timers_fall_here]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor= 0.0
aggregationMethod = average
```

Aggregation can be explained as thus-

Say you pluck apples *daily* and the `no_of_apples` and `time_to_pluck` are stored in a notebook. When your garden owner expects a *monthly* 'report', you aggregate data by averaging the times and by adding the counts.

This similar approach comes in practice when the storage schema shifts in granularity. For instance, if your schema is `10s:1d,60s:7d` then aggregation happens in the `10s to 60s` interval wherein granularity shifts. The 6 data-points in the 1d period need to be stored as a single data-point in the 7d period. How they're aggregated is defined by `aggregationMethod`.

Comment: thanks erbdex. Is it correct say if your using statsd and dont have a storage-aggregation.conf file strange things happen (inaccurate metrics? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474505/getting-accurate-graphite-stats-counts